# How can I fix this error when deploying to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy this repo to Heroku:

https://github.com/trailofbits/tubertc

But I run into this error, I've tried both ways to deploy the app, the provided deploy button and also tried manual way of deploying, both resulted in sam error:

```
    -----> Installing dependencies

       Installing node modules (package.json)

       npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1093-aws

       npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_e9449080/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_e9449080/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--production=false" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_e9449080/.npmrc"

       npm ERR! node v5.12.0

       npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6

       npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

       

       npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1

       npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/tmp/build_e9449080/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)

       npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/tmp/build_e9449080/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)

       npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/tmp/build_e9449080/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:455:12)

       npm ERR! typeerror     at /tmp/build_e9449080/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:7

       npm ERR! typeerror     at /tmp/build_e9449080/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50

       npm ERR! typeerror     at /tmp/build_e9449080/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12

       npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/tmp/build_e9449080/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)

       npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/tmp/build_e9449080/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)

       npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/tmp/build_e9449080/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)

       npm ERR! typeerror     at /tmp/build_e9449080/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50

       npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:

       npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

       

       npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

       npm ERR!     /tmp/build_e9449080/npm-debug.log

-----> Build failed
```

Any thoughts? I tried googling but couldn't really find any solution related to these error messages

Comment: I've found [this](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/4358). Can you try to upgrade Node/NPM?

Comment: Solved! The issue was the very old version of npm, which I changed to v15

Comment: Nice! I'll post the answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The version of *Node* and *NPM* are too old.

You have to **update** them.

Moreover, you also obtain **security** and **performance**.